# How can I print out the value of a git configuration setting (core.autocrlf) on Windows?

Tags: git, newline

I'm trying to fix a problem with CRLF on Windows.

How do I see what the value of the configuration setting `core.autocrlf` is set to on my system?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you're using Git Bash:

```
git config --get core.autocrlf
```

And for the global config:

```
git config --global --get core.autocrlf
```

Comment: It doesn’t print anything out for me. How do I see the calculated value?

Comment: If git does not print anything then the property is not set. this implies that git uses the default-value. the default-value of `core.autocrlf` is `false`.

Comment: `autocrlf` is the mosts idiotic setting set to `true` by default in git. It should be `false`!!!

Answer (score 7):

Where ever your git repo is ie:public_html do:

```
[~/public_html]$ git config -l
```

this should list your whole config for that repo. You could also always use:

```
[~/public_html]$ git config -help
```

this will show you all the list commands

Answer (score 7):

If you want to check your settings, you can use the `git config --list` command to list all the settings Git can find at that point:

```
$ git config --list
user.name=John Doe
user.email=johndoe@example.com
color.status=auto
color.branch=auto
color.interactive=auto
color.diff=auto
...
```

You may see keys more than once, because Git reads the same key from different files (`/etc/gitconfig` and `~/.gitconfig`, for example). In this case, Git uses the last value for each unique key it sees.

You can also check what Git thinks a specific key’s value is by typing `git config <key>`:

```
$ git config user.name
John Doe
```

Here the used [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)

Answer (score 1):

In the .git dir there is a file named 'config' which has your settings in. This help?

Comment: I was expecting this to be a global setting.

Comment: Then I think Chris Missal's answer could be modified to:
git config --global --get core.autocrlf

Comment: @robertlaing: Actually "git config --get core.autocrlf" would pick from **all** config files: per-repository file `.git/config`, if it isn't there from per-user file `%HOME%/.gitconfig` (or something like that; it is `~/.gitconfig` on Unix) ("--global"), and finally if it isn't there from system-wide file, which is `/etc/gitconfig` on Unix ("--system")

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you set that option as global, that can override the local configuration. You can have a try. If it is yes, you don't need care too much about the one inside the git  repo.

Answer (score 0):

To read from particular value from a git configuration files ,

`git config --system –get core.autocrlf`

Reads the value `core.autocrlf` from configuration file of Git set at System level.

There are 3 levels of configuration files for git :

1) Local (use --local)

2) System (use --system)

3) Global (use --global)

*Q) What will happen if I skip to mention the level of a file ?*

In case of **Read operation** , then value will be searched in all the 3 configuration files.

`git config –get core.autocrlf`

*Q) What does it mean if it does not print anything ?*

It simply means , that no such configuration is set.

*Q) What if a configuration value is mentioned in all 3 files ? Which will it show ?*

Well, highest priority to local , then global and then system. Sometimes a config variable can have multiple value , say in local. In that case the last value mentioned in the local config file, it will show.

*Q) What if I want to see all values for a config variable ?*

Use `--get-all` like

`git config --local --get-all core.autocrlf`

*Q) What happens if I write `git config --get-all core.autocrlf` ?*

Clearly you have skipped to write the level of file , hence in that case it shows [for all files and all values mentioned in them for this config variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565345/2844702).