# Where is git config --get-all looking at

Tags: git

I can't find any documentation describing exactly what git configuration files are being checked a `git config --get-all command` is run.  Here's my output when I run it for core.autocrlf.

```
git config --get-all core.autocrlf
false
true
true
```

I'm having some phantom line feed issues and I was wondering if anybody can tell me where that first "false" is coming.  I've read that git is supposed to use the last one, and "true" is the setting I want.  But I'm not sure if it's always using that in every scenario.  Like if I'm using alternative git UI's through eclipse git or through the git GUI applications or something.

I think two places that it's being read from is

REPO_DIR/.git/config
and
WINDOWS_USER_DIR/.gitconfig

But where's this 3rd config setting coming from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Git will check these files in the given order:

- `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`
- `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` or `$HOME/.config/git/config`
- `~/.gitconfig`
- `$GIT_DIR/config`

So the third value likely comes from the system-wide configuration file in `/etc/gitconfig`.

See the [git-config man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES) for further details.

Comment: The OP is on Windows, where's `/etc/gitconfig` ?

Comment: @blackbird57 Git must be installed below some prefix path, and it will be below that same prefix.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have checked that documentation more carefully.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that Git reads the config from the repo `.git/config` and the user home directory `.gitconfig`

You probably have that config duplicated in one of those files, you can manually edit them and check for yourself. Here's a simple test I made on my machine

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[core]
    bare = false

[root@test .git]# git config --get-all core.bare
  false
  false

[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master

[root@test .git]# git config --get-all core.bare
  false
```

Answer (score 0):

Put Simply , from to bottom , first is shows value of System level configuration for Git , then global level configuration and at last it is local level configuration.

If the configuration variable in a particular level of file have many values , then all those values are shown too in the order they are mentioned in that particular config file.